# The probability limit of the inverse of an infinite-dimensional matrix

Tags: convergence, linear-algebra, high-dimensional

I am considering a question regarding the calculation of the probability limit for a high-dimensional inverse matrix.

Specifically, suppose that $A_n, B_n \in \mathbb{R}^{N_n \times N_n}$ where $N_n \to \infty$, whose minimum eigenvalues are bounded below by some positive constant $C$ (independent of $n$).  Let $A_n^{-1}$ and $B_n^{-1}$ denote the inverse matrix of $A_n$ and $B_n$ respectively.

Now my question is the following:

Suppose that $||A_n - B_n|| = o_P(1)$ as $n \to \infty$, where $||\cdot||$ is the Forbinous norm. Then, if it is sufficient to conclude that $||A_n^{-1} - B_n^{-1}|| = o_P(1)$?

I am not sure if this is a well-established fact or if it is simply my claim. I would appreciate it if you can share with me your thoughts on this issue, or let me know any related paper/theory/lemma that you might know.

Thank you in advance. If the question is not clear please also let me know.

Comment: Perhaps on Math Stack you'd have more chances.

Comment: Consider the simplest possible analog of this question where the sequences are *numbers.*  Let, say, $a_n = 2^{-n}$ and $b_n=1/n.$ Their difference converges to zero, but notice that $|a_n^{-1}-b_n^{-1}|=2^n-n$ diverges. This alone shows your conjecture cannot be generally true.

Comment: @whuber, OP says that minimum eigenvalues are bounded from below by some $C>0$ independent of $n$. Do $a_n$ and $b_n$ fit this and if not, does the condition rescue the claim?

Comment: @Christoph This is an edit applied to circumvent the point I made.  It does bar the kinds of exceptions I indicated.